# Continuous transition between additive and multiplicative operator?

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, optimization

### Question

- What is the best way to create a function/operator which can smoothly transition between addition and multiplication?

More specifically, is there an alternative to just calculating the results of both addition and multiplication operations, and weighting between them with a parameter?

Are there considerations with regards to parameter estimation, e.g. via MCMC or SGD?

### Motivation

In time-series models, there are two ways to move between additive or multiplicative model specifications:

- **Whole series transformations on $y$**: Taking the log of the data. This changes the interpretation of every additive operator in the model-specification, into a multiplicative one. The continuous equivalent of this would be the Box-Cox transformation, providing a parameter to weight between the two extremes.
- **Component Operators**: On a per-component basis, changing the operators in our model specification, either $+$ or $\times$. This allows us to, for example, have an additive trend, multiplicative seasonality, and additive errors.

I would like the best of both worlds; a continuous transition between additive and multiplicative assumptions, but on a ***per component*** basis.

Is this possible without estimating both additive and multiplicative terms, and then estimating a parameter to weight between them?

For example, let's say my seasonality component is $20$ parameters; would I need to calculate additive and multiplicative terms and then a parameter to weight between them ($20 \times2 + 1$ parameters), or is it possible to just fit my parameters with a weight on the operator itself ($20+1$ parameters)?

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is `<X>`, and you're wondering
if `<Y>` is a good way to go about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As its written right now, 
the question appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Maybe look into Box-Cox transformation?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, Perhaps; the <X> I'm trying to solve here is a continuous transition between addition and multiplication, performed independently for different parts of a model specification. I think/hope that's reflected well in the title and body of the question, but apologies if it's unclear. Do you idea of what my <X> and <Y> are? My question very specifically mentions and considers the Box-Cox transformation, and contrasts it to my goal.

Comment: Could you then add a concrete example? Or some restrictions on the arguments, like positivity?

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question.)

Such operators have a name, they are called **Non-integer rank Hyperoperations**. They are currently considered and unsolved problem!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227761/example-x-y-and-z-values-for-x-uparrow-alpha-y-z-where-alpha-in-bbb